# Compile Form Data In Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, forms

I've created a form in Excel which has been filled out by many people.  Now I have ten files containing this form which have been filled in and I'd like to compile all the results into one Excel file.  How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This question is really broad and unlikely to get useful answers as is. Could you please provide a sample of what the form data looks like and what kind of output format you would like?

Comment: Hello @Excelll, My form was created using the form tools in excel.  It has radio buttons, checkboxes, listboxes and text fields.  I'd like to pull the data from multiple filled in forms into a database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  You can start a Query by importing all the files in a Folder.  As long as they have a consistent format you will get a single stream of data with all the rows from each file appended.

http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2013/11/26/from-txt-files-to-bi-solution/

You can send the output from a Query to an Excel Table.

Power Query has lots of other functionality to transform and combine data along the way, if you need to.